# default textblock styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have the following checkbox

`<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" Width="74"/>`

and I have a button

`<Button Name="TestButton" Content="Test" />`

I want to set a "default" color for the textblock. I achieve that by having a resourcedictionary which has the following content:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

The problem is, that the Button should still have a black Textblock foreground, but although in another sourcedictionary i have the following, it still changes to white:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                Margin="1"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                TextBlock.Foreground="Black"
                                Opacity="1.0"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate/>
            <Setter.Value/>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style
```

Edit:
The ResourceDictionaries are defined in Application.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="TextBlock.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Buttons.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: In the ContentPresenter, did you try `TextElement.Foreground="Black"` instead of `TextBlock.Foreground`?

Comment: Yeah, `TextElement.Foreground` and `TextBlock.Foreground` both change the Text's color, but are still overwritten by the Other style, sadly.

Comment: How defining another default TextBlock style in `ContentPresenter.Resources`?

Comment: I've updated my Question

Comment: s/How/How about/ -- sorry, I meant that as a suggestion

Comment: That worked! Thanks :) You might want to add this as answer, so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding the default `TextBlock` style locally for the `ContentPresenter` by defining another one in its `Resources`:

```
<ContentPresenter ... >
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

But a better way to set a default control text color is like this in `App.Resources`. `TextElement.Foreground` will override this on any given individual element.

```
<SolidColorBrush 
    x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" 
    Color="White"
    />
```

If you use that and discard your default `TextBlock` style, your original `ContentPresenter` should work as you had it.